# Why didn’t I get the solid gold skins in fortnite

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I am currently level 212 in Fortnite season 2 chapter 4 and I have heard that everyone is supposed to have all of the solid gold skins when they reach level 200 so I’m curious and confused why I don’t have any of them yet so if anyone could help me figure out why and how to get the let me know.
Also for clarification yes I do have the battle pass.
Thanks

Comment: Where did you hear this rumor?